# Update label with SqlDataSource with stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, code-behind

This is my stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_GetDomainServerIps] 
    @handleDomain         NVARCHAR(20)
AS   
BEGIN     
    SET NOCOUNT ON;   

    SELECT 
        mail_config.dom_handle, mail_config.max_pop, 
        mail_config.max_alias, mail_config.max_redir, 
        mail_config.max_size, mail_config.srvGroup, 
        mail_config.config_date_cre, mail_config.is_active, 
        server.srvGroup, server.srvIP, server.srvNom, 
        server.service AS srvType
    FROM 
        [services].[dbo].mail_config 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        [Namebay].[dbo].[server] ON server.srvGroup = mail_config.srvGroup 
    WHERE 
        mail_config.dom_handle = @handleDomain 
        AND server.service in ('pop', 'smtp', 'webmail', 'mx', 'mx2') 
    ORDER BY 
        Service ASC, srvNom ASC 
END
```

I want to return `server.srvIP`, `server.srvNom` and `server.srvType` in differents labels using code behind under Visual Studio

I try this :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="x_oInfosDomains" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:hostingConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="P_GetDomainServerIps" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="handleDomain" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="x_lblSrvType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("srvType")%>' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="x_lblSrvName" runat="server" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="x_lblPublicIP" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi, this can help you, first answer on page (only the difference is that they have asp:textbox and you have asp:Label): https://forums.asp.net/t/1308964.aspx?Setting+Label+Text+Result+from+a+SQLDataSource . If you need more help say me please !!!

Comment: My problem comes from the fact that my stored procedure has only one parameter and that I want to retrieve my variables rather than my parameter in my labels

Comment: You want to retrieve 3 select return values and set in 3 labels, no?. First: Where is your code behind?, Second: Where are you calling stored procedure with the value for @handleDomain? If i have time i will put you some code example if you clarify me these points